# Sending an email to a responsible user

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a script that sends a mail to a person responsible for tasks on a given day.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    xToday = Format(Now, "MM/DD/YYYY") 'change format to match yours

    Set findToday = Range("A1:B" & Range("A" & _
    Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Find(xToday, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not findToday Is Nothing Then
        person = Range("B" & findToday.Row)
        If person = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "No person assigned for today"
            End
        End If
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set olMail = olApp.createitem(0)
        With olMail
        .Subject = "xxx SHIFT"
        .to = "xxx"
        .cc = "person4@emailaddy.com"
        .bcc = ""
        .body = "Today, " & vbNewLine & person & " is responsible for doing stuff."
        .send
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not find the date"
    End If
End Sub
```

something is wrong with this...i gueess with the format of the date? as all the time I get the popup "could not find the date"...
I tried with all data format combinations - but no luck 
[image]

Anyone could help?

Comment: The line that starts Set FindToday.. what is it supposed to do?

Comment: confirm that all the dates in sheet are in excel date format, if they are, xToday does not require Now to be formatted.

Comment: I mean what kind of value are you expecting in findToday after that - something like "A1:B10"?

Comment: all of them are formatted as date. I also tried without formatting. But the same. Is it not the case that in vba  NOW function requires also hours and minutes whereas in cells there is not time provided?

Comment: column A are dates and column B are names so... string I guess?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something small, that would work for you:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim xToday      As Date
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim findToday   As Range

    xToday = DateValue(Now)
    With Worksheets(1)
        Set searchRange = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set findToday = searchRange.Find(xToday)
        findToday.Select
    End With

End Sub
```

I have additionally declared `Worksheets(1)`, in order to avoid working with the `ActiveWorksheet`.
The idea is that you define the ranges correctly and you use `DateValue()`, which returns only the day and not the time. To see the difference, run this:

```
Debug.Print Now
Debug.Print DateValue(Now)
```

---

Concerning your screenshot and the fact that you are using different dates setting than VBA, it is probably better to take the following approach - use `Application.Match` to locate the row, where the date is. The column seems to be a constant, thus always 1. If you locate the row, then set `findToday` to the cell with this row, on the first column. If you do not locate the row, the `findRow` variable is assigned to `-1` and thus on the 2. condition you get `MsgBox "Not Found"`. Copy exactly this code and give it a try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim xToday      As Long
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim findToday   As Range

    xToday = DateValue(Now)
    With Worksheets(1)
        Set searchRange = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        Dim findRow As Long
        If IsError(Application.Match(xToday, searchRange.Columns(1), 0)) Then
            findRow = -1
        Else
            findRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(xToday, searchRange.Columns(1), 0)
        End If

        If findRow = -1 Then
            MsgBox "NOT FOUND!"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set findToday = .Cells(findRow, 1)
            findToday.Select ' in your case - send the mail, do not select
        End If     

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, and how to incorporate this with the IF part of my code? I am trying but again no luck...

Comment: @Adam - try like this `If Not findToday Is Nothing Then`. And remove the `findToday.Select` from my code, it is just for the example.

Comment: would you be able to provide the whole script as I am trying to make it all working but i have the errors..for instance a kind of a variable is not found. , ,

Comment: @Adam - remove the `Option Explicit` line from my code and these errors would be gone. Or declare the variables (better option!)

Comment: did the following and ..still  'could not find the date'...I incorporated if within a loop.

Comment: @Adam - try a bit different approach. Just use my code and a few dates in range `A1:B10` for example. Run the code. Does it work?

Comment: @ Vityata, I would like to have dates only in column A - column B would include the names

Comment: I added a print screen in the main topic. As simple as that 2 columns one with date another with name..

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and still 'could not find the date' pops up:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()



Dim xToday      As Date
Dim searchRange As Range


xToday = DateValue(Now)
With Worksheets(1)
    Set searchRange = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("A" & 
.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set findToday = searchRange.Find(xToday)

If Not findToday Is Nothing Then
    person = Range("B" & findToday.Row)
    If person = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "No person assigned for today"
        End
    End If
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.createitem(0)
    With olMail
    .Subject = "xxx SHIFT"
    .to = "xxx"
    .cc = "person4@emailaddy.com"
    .bcc = ""
    .body = "Today, " & vbNewLine & person & " is responsible for doing 
     stuff."
    .send
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Could not find the date"
End If

End With


End Sub
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of columns A and B? And declare `Dim findToday   As Range`.